# How to go beyond the 26 file limit in the appendix?

Tags: appendices

**Update 08/5/2020 (incorporating latest suggestions)**

I'm currently working on a large LaTeX document with (so far) 26 appendices files which are incorporated via `\include`. Comments helpfully diagnosed the issue as being the labelling system, when trying to add a 27th and failing, however, implementing an `\alphalpha` solution on the `\begin{appendices' section is still causing me some issues.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,authoryear,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF} 
% The class file, `PhDThesisPSnPDF`, is based on the standard `book` class

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\include{Dedication/dedication}
\include{Declaration/declaration}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\include{Abstract/abstract}

\mainmatter

\include{01/chapter1}
\include{02/chapter2}
\include{03/chapter3}
\include{04/chapter4}
\include{05/chapter5}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Use for unsorted references  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % use this to have URLs listed in References
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{References/library} % Path to your References.bib file

\begin{appendices} 

    \include{Appendix_01/appendix_01}
    \include{Appendix_02/appendix_02}
    \include{Appendix_26/appendix_26}
    \include{Appendix_27/appendix_27}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I've been trying to get AA, AB etc. working using the alphalph package and including the below in curly braces just under `/begin{appendices}`. I understand this should limit the renew command to this section? Each appendix starts with \chapter{Title}, but perhaps I shouldn't be using `\thechapter`? The below causing a large number of errors, but have been trying alternates to see it might work:

```
\begin{appendices} 
    {
        \usepackage{alphalph}
        \renewcommand*{\thechapter}
        \AlphAlph{\value{chapter}}%

    \include{Appendix_01/appendix_01}
    \include{Appendix_02/appendix_02}
    \include{Appendix_26/appendix_26}
    \include{Appendix_27/appendix_27}
    }   
\end{appendices}
```

No luck so far. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How would you number the 27th appendix? Not with a single letter, of course.

Comment: Ah! Of course! I will look into how lettering/numbering is being controlled. Thanks @egreg

Comment: Maybe loading the `alphalph` package?

Comment: @egreg do you have a suggestion to change from letter to numerical value?

Comment: Bsides alphalph, there is \Roman as in `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}`.

Comment: Have added an update with a MWE, spot on with alphalph or Roman being the way forward, but my implementation seems to not be working - either due to referring to external files through my .tex or (more likely) because I'm implementing incorrectly.

Comment: What's the reason for `\begin{appendices}` instead of a simple `\appendix` command? By the way, if you use the `appendix` package (you have no apparent reason to) and `\begin{appendices}`, then patching `\appendix` does nothing at all.

Comment: The question doesn't identify the document class.  That information would be helpful.

Comment: @egreg - great question! I have been using this as it was part of the [original template](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template) created and had no reason to change till now. I found that changing this section to `\appendix` meant that my chapter numbering continued into the appendix which wasn't ideal.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Apologies, have added the documentclass in the MWE. This is a custom template which I understand is based on the book class.